# Docker-Compose cannot find new node module

Tags: docker, npm, module, installation, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose with multiple different projects and everything works perfectly fine in the beginning. But whenever I install a new module, docker is not able to find it. Even when I use docker-compose build with the --no-cache flag.

These are my Docker and my docker-compose files:

```
FROM node:6.11.3
RUN npm install -g gulp && npm install -g node-gyp
COPY ./ /usr/apps
WORKDIR /usr/apps
RUN ls
RUN npm install
CMD gulp serve
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=dockerenv
    links:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/apps/
      - /usr/apps/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
      - /data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Try using `docker-compose up --build` and see if that helps?

Comment: That didn't help but I found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution by accident. I deleted all docker containers and all docker images by running:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

and 
    docker-compose rm -f

After that I simply typed docker-compose build and docker-compose up and everything worked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, keep in mind `containers are cattle, not pets`. Recommended reading: http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/